How do you disable xauth in X11 CDE?
I am using FreeBSD 14.1 with CDE (https://sourceforge.net/projects/cdesktopenv/)
I would like to disable xauth and use just xhost.
I am unsure if this has to be done via Xorg server configuration (FreeBSD) or via CDE config files.
This is what I have tried:

Modify /etc/dt/config/Xconfig:

Dtlogin*authorize:         False


Delete user's .Xauthority file.

